# CreateNotBook via RESTapi for MSonenote 365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

While creating Notebook in MS365 authorized account via REST api call .I am facing some issue ,could anyone let me know what changes I have to make for this.

Request:

```
 POST - https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks
Body : {
    "name": "MSOneNoteBusiness_OSSA_5LyC"
}
```

Response

```
Body : {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/8dc0a74f-0aa6-45f4-813b-92e910f40bd4/notes/notebooks",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "fa409682-5395-4189-a43c-757adcfaea35",
      "date": "2017-06-28T10:08:06"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The request should be POST `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks`, not `/me/notes`, and the request body should have the property `displayName`.  We also have a sample for this in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):

[image: onenote samples in graph explorer]

[image: creating onenote notebook]